# Change colour of an element when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot figure out how to change the colour of my menu elements when the "`center`" container or the "`right`" container is clicked (returning its state once clicked on again).
Currently my 3 lines that are within my menu are white, I want to change them to red when these "`center`" and "`right`" containers are clicked.

**HTML** for menu and containers:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class= "container" id= "center">
        <h1 style="color:white"><a>LOREM IPSUM<a/></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id= "right">
        <h1 style="color:white"><a>LOREM IPSUM</a></h1>
    </div>
```

**CSS** for menu elements:

```
.menu .line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22.5px;
  left: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
  z-index: 100;
}
.menu .line:after, .menu .line:before {
  content: ' ';
  height: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.menu .line:before {
  top: -10px;
}
.menu .line:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define new classes for the colors you want, e.g.

```
.red {
    color: red !important;
}
.green {
    color: green !important;
}
```

Then toggle them using jQuery:

```
$('#center').click(function() {
    $(this).find('h1').toggleClass('red');
});
$('#right').click(function() {
    $(this).find('h1').toggleClass('green');
});
```

Note: If you assign the original color using CSS then you don't need the !important.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to make sense of your sample html, so here's is an [example demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stg1x3bn/) using jQuery's `.toggleClass`

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onClick()` method

Html:

```
<h1 style="color:white" onclick="changeColor(this);"><a>LOREM IPSUM<a/></h1>
```

and add this function in the `<script>` tag:

```
function changeColor(element){
    element.style.color='red';
}
```